# Not able to control env_logger on a module basis vis RUST_LOG

Tags: logging, rust

I'm having an issue where I'm incorporating log/env_logger in my code.

I've loggging incoroprated and it appears to be working correctly if I enable things at a global level (RUST_LOG=debug) or at a application level (RUST_LOG=testlogapp) but if I try to enable logging at a module level (RUST_LOG=main) it doesn't seem to work.

**Cargo.toml**:

```
    [package]
    name = "test_log_app"
    version = "0.1.0"
    edition = "2021"
        
    [dependencies]
    env_logger = "0.9.0"
    log = "0.4.16"
```

**src/main.rs**

```
#[macro_use] extern crate log;

fn main() {
    env_logger::init();

    debug!("this is a debug {}", "message");
    error!("this is printed by default");

    let x = 3 * 4; 
    info!("the answer was: {}", x);
}
```

The results I get are ase follows:

**RUST_LOG=debug** -- WORKS

```
$ RUST_LOG=debug cargo run
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.01s
     Running `target/debug/test_log_app`
[2022-06-22T16:36:40Z DEBUG test_log_app] this is a debug message
[2022-06-22T16:36:40Z ERROR test_log_app] this is printed by default
[2022-06-22T16:36:40Z INFO  test_log_app] the answer was: 12
```

**RUST_LOG=info**  -- WORKS

```
$ RUST_LOG=info cargo run
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.01s
     Running `target/debug/test_log_app`
[2022-06-22T16:36:47Z ERROR test_log_app] this is printed by default
[2022-06-22T16:36:47Z INFO  test_log_app] the answer was: 12
```

by application name **RUST_LOG=test_log_app**  -- WORKS

```
$ RUST_LOG=test_log_app cargo run
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.00s
     Running `target/debug/test_log_app`
[2022-06-22T16:36:55Z DEBUG test_log_app] this is a debug message
[2022-06-22T16:36:55Z ERROR test_log_app] this is printed by default
[2022-06-22T16:36:55Z INFO  test_log_app] the answer was: 12
```

By Module **RUST_LOG=main**  -- **FAILS** with no logging output

```
$ RUST_LOG=main cargo run
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.01s
     Running `target/debug/test_log_app`
```

From the docs I expect RUST_LOG=main should enable the logging as well...
Am I missing something or doing something incorrectly?
Much thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you expect `RUST_LOG=main` to work?

Comment: From the env_logger documentation -> https://docs.rs/env_logger/latest/env_logger/

In particular 
A logging directive is of the form:

example::log::target=level

and they give the example of values for RUST_LOG including *hello turns on all logging for the ‘hello’ module*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the module of the file `main.rs` is **not** `main`. It is the name of the crate.

Proof:

```rust
use std::path::PathBuf;

use itertools::Itertools;
use regex::Regex;

fn main() {
    let cargo_toml_path = PathBuf::from(env!("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR")).join("Cargo.toml");
    let cargo_toml = std::fs::read_to_string(cargo_toml_path).unwrap();
    let package_name_regex = Regex::new(r#"name = "(.*)""#).unwrap();
    let crate_name = package_name_regex
        .captures_iter(&cargo_toml)
        .exactly_one()
        .expect("no package name or more than one `name` key in Cargo.toml")
        .get(1)
        .unwrap()
        .as_str();

    println!("file       = {}", file!());
    println!("crate name = {}", crate_name);
    println!("module     = {}", module_path!());
}
```

[Output in the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d11f89ce4641afda690cde99cb7ac3b4):

```
file       = src/main.rs
crate name = playground
module     = playground
```

Comment: Thank you -- that was exactly what I needed. WIth he right naming convention I'm able to correctly control in both the main and other modules.